# Is it possible deleted partially?

Tags: sql-server, restore, transaction

I executed delete query

`delete from [table_name]`

After execution, I found that 'where clause' is wrong so I cancelled the query using cancel buttion in SSMS.

[image: cancel buttion in ssms]

and then I counted the table record.
I don't know exact previous table record but it is less than 100000 record what am i expected

Is it possible deleted partially?

also I searched delete query in sys.dm_exec_query_stats table
but there is no delete query.

If there is no delete query in sys.dm_exec_query_stats table,
then It can't be deleted, Is it right?
(Always Query execution remain in sys.dm_exec_query_stats table, right? or Although there is no query execution in dm_exec_query_stats table, could it be execute?)

And Is there any way that I can find previous table information? (like table record count)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Either the entire `DELETE` statement ran to completion and it deleted all rows that the incorrect `WHERE` clause covered or the statement was aborted in time and the deletes were all rolled back. It is not possible that only "some" were deleted